# C# - 'Could not convert string to integer: 2174837884.' Break. Can't seem to figure out where I am even doing so?

Tags: c#

Getting the error that's provided in the title with the following code:

```
var TopScores = await osuApi.GetScoresAsync(857477);
```

On GetScoresAsync:

```
public async Task<ReadOnlyCollection<Scores>> GetScoresAsync(long b, object u = null, Mods m = 0, int limit = 50)
    {
        var request = CreateRequestGetScores(ApiKey, b, u, m, limit);
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return ParseGetScores(await new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEndAsync());
        }
    }
```

ParseGetScores:

```
private static ReadOnlyCollection<Scores> ParseGetScores(string jsonString)
    {
        IList<Scores> result = new List<Scores>();
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(jsonString))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            while (jsonReader.Read())
            {
                if (jsonReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                    result.Add(new Scores(jsonReader));
            }
        }
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Scores>(result);
    }
```

Somewhere here it throws this at me:

```
Osu.Utils.JsonReaderException: 'Could not convert string to integer: 2174837884.'
```

EDIT: The reason I can't pinpoint exactly where it errors is because this code is taken from a library(dll) which I can only view in it's own project form and not debug directly

Comment: `new Scores(jsonReader)` You create a new `Scores` object from json. There's most likely your error.

Comment: Guess you should use `long` instead of `int`

Comment: Please show us the `scores` constructor and the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, Gill Bates: Unsure how I should not be doing that as the list is based on Scores, don't see any other way to add the result in the Scores list

To Amy:
Seems like it is too long for stackoverflows character limit for comments, hmm

Comment: @T.Std for additional new information like that it is expected you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43641095/edit) and put the information there.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. *edit the question*

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing the `Scores` class, but `Scores` likely has a property, perhaps like this:

```
public int Score { get; set;}
```

and the json that you are trying to read likely has this

```
Scores: [{ Score: 2174837884 },{Score: 2 }, ...]
```

The `JsonTextReader` uses reflection or some other method to initialize the `Scores` class and when it sees that the value 2,174,837,884 is too big to fit into an int, rather than truncating the int, it is nice and throws an exception. The largest value that an int can hold in c# is 2,147,483,647.

Hopefully you can change the `Scores` class and make the `int` a `long`, otherwise you may have to catch this Exception and have some way to handle it.

Comment: Another option also is to go to a `uint` instead of a `int` if you can never have a negitive score.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/xicukireve.cs - Was able to upload the Scores Constructor on hastebin! Your previous input is greatly appreciated! However I wish it was as simple as just having an int laying around, The library was originally not made by me so I am not fully aware of what I'm looking at.

Comment: Link is broken. Links are generally bad to post on SO because they are unreliable. Probably best to post the code in your question

Comment: `internal Scores(JsonTextReader jsonReader)

        {

            long Depth = jsonReader.Depth;

            while (jsonReader.Read())
`

Then it goes on to a switch case that is irrelevant, but only reference I can find to how Scores is define is just an internal call @spectacularbob

EDIT: Code snippet bunches up into 1 line :s